# VB.net LINQ select specific rows from datatable

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I have s situation where i load all my data in a DataTable, but i need to use only the columns which don't start with a prefix ("#") in my case.
I could build a function to go through the data, but i wanted to use LINQ as i'm in the process of learning it.

What i have so far:

```
Dim l = (From r In (dt.AsEnumerable())
                     From c As DataColumn
                             In r.Table.Columns
                     Where Not c.ColumnName.Contains("#")).ToList()
```

But the result is not what i need.
I realize what's wrong with the function but i just can't figure out how to write it

To make it more clear:

```
DataTable:
      [Column1][Column2][Column3]
[Row1]    123      abv   12/10/21
[Row2]    555     sfsf   12/12/21
```

I don't need [Column3] and, because of the specific of what i'm trying to do, i need to use the complete DataTable. So, the result would be:

```
DataTable, or List(of) or IEnumerable..:
      [Column1][Column2]
[Row1]    123      abv   
[Row2]    555     sfsf
```

And i was hoping to use LINQ, but if it's to complicated, or not possible, i will use the normal vb way. i'll build a new DataTable with only the desired columns...

Comment: Why don't you use `StartsWith`, which does exactly what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a Select if you know which columns you want to keep

```
dim result = dt.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(x) New With {
       Key .Col1 = x.Field(Of String)("Column1"),
       Key .Col2 = x.Field(Of String)("Column2")
   }).Tolist()
```

Or else you can do

```
dim result = dt.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(x) New With {
       Key .Col1 = x.Field(Of String)("Column1"),
       Key .Col2 = x.Field(Of String)("Column2"),
       'put every field.....
   }).Where(Function(y) Not y.Col3.StartsWith("#"c)).Tolist()
```

Comment: i've edited my question to make it more clear, hopefully. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: ok nice, i've edited the answer aswell, let me know if that's what you needed

Comment: Yes! The second one was almost what i needed. The thing is, the column names and column count are variables. I have multiple SQL strings in a table on a server from which i need to generate some HTML tables. The thing is, some of the Columns start with #, and those are not needed to the output. So the question is: is there a way to iterate the <<   Key .Col1 = x.Field(Of String)("Column1"), >> based on the number of Columns in the dt? Something like << From c As DataColumn In dt.Columns Where c.ColumnName.StartsWith("#") >>

Comment: I will set this as answered because this is the closest to what i wanted. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I think I understand what you need now. You do not want `Dim result = datatable.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(y) Not y.Field(Of String)("Column1").StartsWith("#"c)).ToList()` something like this, because you do not know the names of the columns right? And you want to iterate using linq. So if that's the case the answer is: you can't do it with Linq. At least with datatables. You won't end up with something like `column.ColumnName.StartsWith("#"c)` unless you iterate with For Each. My suggestion would be to use entity framework, if you can of course.

Comment: Yes. That was exactly what i wanted. Thanks for the answer. What is entity framework?

Comment: go in visual studio, manage nuget packages and you will find it. I use version 6.4.4. It's an open source framework that treats your database as an object-relational entity. So you'll be able to write queries in your code with linq since your database will be treated as a list of lists of objects: Database is a list of tables and tables are a list of objects (single records)

Comment: Thank you so much. I will give it a try :)\

Answer (score 0):

This is what i ended up with. I just remove the column i don't need from the collection.

```
dt.Columns.Remove((From c As DataColumn In dt.Columns Where c.ColumnName.StartsWith("#")).First)
```

Comment: You didn't say only one column would be removed from the answer.

Comment: I know, but hat was the only i could do it. Actually @lorenzo's answer was closest to what i wanted.